# get current visitor country code in shopify liquid file

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

how I get current visitor country code in shopify liquid file?

`{{ localization.country.iso_code }}`

I use this code but not working. it's always get store location country code.

Comment: There is no `localization` object. There is the `request` object that can be helpful, but you won't get the country from the liquid file. https://www.shopify.com/ca/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet?shpxid=92f6645a-BD01-49F3-EBAF-E963F907C263

Comment: There is a `localization` Liquid object. It's in the docs here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/localization#localization-country

The code is OP is using is correct. You can see the same code used to determine the currently selected storefront location in an uncustomised Shopify theme (such as Dawn) in the `country-localization.liquid` file. 

You access the country object to then access the `iso_code`: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/country

In OPs case, I don't know why it wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 5):

I know a way to get the country but not the code.

Let's assume you have an HTML element in some page that you want to display the country name inside

```html
<p class="visitor-country-name"></p>
```

1. First install the free app (made by Shopify) called [Geolocation](https://apps.shopify.com/geolocation).
2. Then put this JS code somewhere in that page inside < script > tags

```js
fetch('browsing_context_suggestions.json')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(r=> document.querySelector(".blog__title.h1").innerHTML = r.detected_values.country.name)
```

This will get the json file containing the visitor information, extract the 'detected_values.country.name' value from it, and inject it to the HTML element 'p' with the class name 'visitor-country-name'.

To see all available information visit the url below (replace 'store-name' with your store name)

> store-name.myshopify.com/browsing_context_suggestions.json